# Heroku: Failed to compile Elm app while deploying a copy of an app

Tags: heroku, elm

I am trying to make a copy of [this](https://github.com/Lattyware/massivedecks) Elm web-app with Heroku. When I click 'Deploy App' however, the build log displays this:

```
-----> Source app detected
-----> Creating profile.d script
       SOURCE_VERSION: 
       Script installed to .profile.d/source_version.sh
-----> Elm app detected
-----> Retrieving 0.18.0
https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-elm/assets/elm/0.18.0/elm:
2018-10-22 04:07:13 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Elm app.
 !     Push failed
```

I have checked the app.json file and I didn't notice anything strange with it. Could this be related to the issues that Github is having right now (in Australia at least)? Am I doing something wrong? As soon as Github have fixed their issue I will try making an issue there, but the last commit was 2 years ago so that probably wouldn't do much. Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/srid/heroku-buildpack-elm/issues/26

Comment: @glennsl that is an open issue, with no comments, from over a year ago. What am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: You might take it as an indication that it's likely permanently broken, the author doesn't seem to care and since noone has bothered or been able to provide any more information in the past year it seems very unlikely that anyone here would be able to provide an answer. Based on that, you could then rephrase this question into something that might actually be answerable, like "How to deploy an Elm app on Heroku?" while referencing this approach being broken. Or you could subscribe to the issue and hope someone replies with something in the next year or so.

Comment: Is the issue related to not being able to access GitHub or AWS? I briefly took a look at the [source code of Heroku buildpack Elm](https://github.com/srid/heroku-buildpack-elm/blob/master/upload-to-s3.sh) and it seems to expect you have `.aws/credential` file with correct access keys set on the docker image.

Comment: For a single page app, why not just compile the elm to index.html and host on github pages? If it does require a backend server, just compile the elm app to JS and then include the JS file in your asset pipeline and follow the directions for deploying to heroku with the backend of your choice.